# Proving that the Wardrop/Nash equilibirum flow on a graph is "stable"?

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, nash-equilibrium, network-flow

Let $[0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ be denoted $\mathbb{R}_{[0, 1]}$. Let $[0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be denoted $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Let $G$ be a finite, connected graph. Associate with each edge $e_j$ of $G$ a function $l_j:  \mathbb{R}_{[0, 1]} \mapsto \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. We assume that $l_j$ are continuous and weakly increasing.

Mark two vertices on it $s$ and $t$, for "source" and "destination" respectively.

Let $\mathcal{P}_{st}$ be the set of paths (sequence of edges) connecting $s$ and $t$. Let $P_{st} = |\mathcal{P}_{st}|$. Let $\mathbf{f} \in \mathbb{R}_{[0, 1]}^{P_{st}}$ be a $P_{st}$-vector, with all elements in $[0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $f_i$ be the $i$th element of $\mathbf{f}$. We say that $\mathbf{f}$ is a flow on $G$ if:
$$ \|\mathbf{f}\|_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} |f_i| = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} f_i = 1 $$
In other words $\mathbf{f}$ represents the fraction of the total flow, which is assumed to be 1, going through the $i$th path.

Let $e \in G$ be an edge. The induced flow in an edge is:
$$F_e = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} p_i(e)f_i$$

Where $p_i(e) = 0$ if $e \not\in \mathcal{P}_i \in \mathcal{P}_{st}$ ($e$ is not an edge in the path $\mathcal{P}_i$), where $\mathcal{P}_i$ is a path from $s$ to $t$. If $e \in \mathcal{P}_i$, then $p_i(e) = 1$. Thus, $F_e$ is the sum of the fraction of the flow in each path which uses edge $e$.

The latency on an edge $e$ is $L_e(F_e)$.

The latency of a path $\mathcal{P}_i$ is given by:
$$ L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f}) = \sum_{e \in \mathcal{P}_i} l_e(F_e)$$
In other words, $L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f})$ is the sum of the latencies of the edges contained in $\mathcal{P}_i$.

We say that a flow $\tilde{\mathbf{f}}$ is a (Nash) equilibirium flow if:
$$ \forall i,j \in \{1, 2, \dots, P_{st}\} | L(\mathcal{P}_i, \tilde{\mathbf{f}}) = L(\mathcal{P}_j, \tilde{\mathbf{f}})$$

The average latency of the network under some flow $\mathbf{f}$ is:
$$ L_G(\mathbf{f}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} f_i L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f})$$

Note that if $\mathbf{f}$ is an equilibrium flow, then the latency of each path in it is the same; call this latency $L^*$, so the average latency of the network is:
$$ L_G(\mathbf{f}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} f_i L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} f_i L^* = L^* $$
because $\sum_i f_i = 1$.

Let $\mathbf{g}$ be some other flow. Then the average latency of $G$ due to flow $\mathbf{g}$ under latencies determined by $\mathbf{f}$ is:
$$ L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f})) = \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} g_i L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f})$$

**Fact:** if $\mathbf{f}$ is an equilibrium flow, then:
$$ L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f})) - L_G(\mathbf{f}) \geq 0 $$

I am having trouble proving the above fact. I know that:

$$ L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f})) - L_G(\mathbf{f}) = L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f})) - L^* = \left(\sum_{i}g_iL^*\right) - L^*$$ 
but it is not obvious to me why:
$$ \sum_{i} g_i L^* \geq L^*, $$
since $\sum_{i} g_i = 1$.

Yet, I do expect that the latency $L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f}))$ should be larger than $L^*$, because if I imagine $\mathbf{g}$ to be a perturbation of $\mathbf{f}$, that is I take a tiny bit of flow from one path and add it to the flow of another path, then I would expect that the latency of the perturbed network should be worse, so that the flow I re-allocated would naturally want to go back to its original allocation.

I suspect that I might have defined an equilibrium flow incorrectly? This result is noted in the following sources:

- https://theory.stanford.edu/~tim/papers/optima.pdf (Proposition 2.4)
- https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~karlin/GameTheoryBook.pdf (Ch. 8, Proposition 8.1.6)

In both cases, the results find it obvious to go from the definition of (Wardrop/Nash) equilibrium to the fact that: 
$$ \sum_{i} g_i L^* \geq L^* $$
However, this is far from obvious to me, perhaps it might be obvious to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for a Nash equilibrium flow is not

$$L(\mathcal{P}_i, \tilde{\mathbf{f}}) = L(\mathcal{P}_j, \tilde{\mathbf{f}}).$$
for all $i,j.$
The condition is $$f_i>0\implies L(\mathcal{P}_i, \tilde{\mathbf{f}}) \leq L(\mathcal{P}_j, \tilde{\mathbf{f}})$$
for all $i,j,$ or equivalently $$f_i>0\implies L(\mathcal{P}_i, \tilde{\mathbf{f}}) =\min_jL(\mathcal{P}_j, \tilde{\mathbf{f}})=:L^*$$
for all $i.$

This can be interpreted as saying that no-one can benefit by choosing a different path than the one they are using. Moving to an unused path can still increase latency.

If all the paths are used ($f_i>0$ for all $i$) then you are correct that $L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f}))=L^*,$ so perturbing the flow does not increase this quantity. $L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f}))$ is a kind of linear approximation to $L(\mathbf{g})$ for $\mathbf{g}\approx\mathbf{f},$ analogous to a tangent plane for a differentiable function, so you might expect it to have zero slope at a critical point in the interior of its domain. (It's not quite a tangent because it's selfish and ignores the change in $L_e(f_e)$.)

That explains why we get inequalities rather than equalities. The fact can be proved as:
\begin{align}
L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f}))
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} g_i L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f})\\
&\geq \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} g_i L^*\\
&= L^*\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{P_{st}} f_i L(\mathcal{P}_i, \mathbf{f})\\
&= L_G(\mathbf{f}).
\end{align}

Comment: With the definition you have suggested (which is, the proper definition, I was working with a misguided "consequence" of it, which was of my own invention), how does one match it up to the Prop. 8.1.6, which suggests that $L_G(\mathbf{g}|L(\mathbf{f}) \geq L^*$? Is this when all the paths are not used, so you get some $>$ cases, because if an path could be used with a lower cost, then it would already cater some traffic, so if it is not catering to any traffic, then it must be that it is more expensive than every used path, even with no traffic on it?

Comment: @user89: I've added a derivation of that inequality